# How do I disable the Welcome Screen in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, login, user-accounts

Right now when I turn on this user's laptop  it boots up into Vista and displays a Welcome / logon screen.  Here my choices are Administrator and User.  Both are admin account types.

Two part question:

1) You can not delete the administrator account because the system uses it.  Am I able to hide it from this welcome screen?

2) Would there be a way to disable this welcome / log on screen all together?  In other words, set it up so that on boot, it just boots directly into User's Desktop?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) You can not delete the
>   administrator account because the
>   system uses it. Am I able to hide it
>   from this welcome screen?

**[Hide Administrator from Welcome Screen in Vista](http://unsharptech.com/2009/01/22/hide-administrator-from-welcome-screen-in-vista/)**

> 2) Would there be a way to disable
>   this welcome / log on screen all
>   together? In other words, set it up so
>   that on boot, it just boots directly
>   into User's Desktop?

click Start and type **netplwiz** in the Search field and then press Enter. Click Continue when the User Account Control window appears.

in the GUI window that comes up, uncheck the “Users must enter a username and password to use this computer” box

click ‘Apply’

in the new dialog box that opens type the name of the account you want to auto-logon by default (if the account is not normally passworded then it blank)

click OK and exit